# Update record in table if it exists (with clause) or creates it if not

Tags: php, mysql, records, mysql5

I am attempting to write a query that will update the record if it exists, or create it if it does not, *however* I want to do that based on the condition that `text_value` is not already set.

I initally thought of using `REPLACE`, but that does not support a `WHERE` clause.

```
REPLACE INTO settings
    SET var_name = '',
        var_group = '',
        text_value = '',
        country_id = ''
```

Can I do what I want to do in one query? I am trying to do so without having to write something like this where I have two queries in my PHP:

`SELECT FROM settings WHERE text_value != '' AND country_id = $country_id`

**IF that returns no results then**

`INSERT INTO settings...`

This is my table DDL information:

```
CREATE TABLE `settings` (
  `settings_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `var_name` varchar(50) default NULL,
  `var_group` varchar(26) NOT NULL,
  `text_value` text NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`settings_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Which record do you want to update?

Comment: `REPLACE` requires you to include a unique key in the list of columns you're updating, so that it can tell whether to update or insert.

Comment: Could you show some sample table data and the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I can think of a hack using `INSERT IGNORE INTO...SELECT...` with a limited `UNION` (maybe), but would is the result supposed to be? If the record with the given `country_id` already exists with a nonempty `text_value`, then all other columns are to be updated?

Comment: To do this in one query, you'll probably need to make `country_id` a unique key.